# dotnet publish does not use version restored by dotnet restore

Tags: .net, nuget, dotnet-restore, dotnet-publish

I'm trying to build a .NET Core application that references a NuGet package from a custom feed (I gave up on authentication so it has anonymous access enabled).

I have a local Teamcity instance that runs a `dotnet publish` command. I added the `--no-restore` flag en prepended a `dotnet restore` task in the Teamcity pipeline so I can specify my custom NuGet server using a `--source` parameter.

My `publish` folder however persistently end up with "My Library" version `0.0.1` instead of the latest version `0.0.2`.

I figured it would be caching and prepended the following command:

> dotnet nuget locals --clear all

This actually made the `dotnet restore` command iterate the packages and I can see it *restoring* version `0.0.2`. But where is this actually restored to? The following `dotnet publish --no-restore` command doesn't seem to take this restored version into account...

Also [further inspection on NuGet caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders) makes it even more weird as both those locations contain the `0.0.2` version of the library... (`%userprofile%\.nuget\packages` and `%localappdata%\NuGet\v3-cache` for both my local user as well as the buildagent user)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try to run this command with `--verbosity diag` flag to see what's going on.

Comment: I do see mixed "references" to both `0.0.1` and `0.0.2` appearing in the diagnostic log for `dotnet publish`. The NuGet version referenced in the log entry seems to be correctly `0.0.2` however there is a *FusionName* in assemblyname-syntax that specifies `0.0.1` in the same line... I still don't understand how this is possible though... The only place I can find the library dll with the `0.0.1` version is in the `/publish` directory from the app. If I `dotnet clear`, `dotnet restore` and `dotnet publish` "manually" (not using the agent) it just takes the right `0.0.2` version to `/publish`...

Comment: I was able to work around it now by adding another build step that just adds the package explicitly just before the restore. Somehow that magically fools everyone :)